# Showing that projection map on Cartesian products is surjective requires axiom of choice?

Tags: set-theory

I'm studying Halmos' *Naive Set Theory*. In Section 9, *Families*, he mentions of the generalized Cartesian products of families of sets, and considers the projection maps as defined below.

Let $\{X_i\}_{i\in I}$ be a family and $J\subset I$. Then the map $f:\Pi_{i\in I}X_i\to\Pi_{j\in J}(X|J)_j$ defined by $f(x) = x|J$ for all $x\in \Pi_{i\in I}X_i$. Halmos call this map as projection from $\Pi_{i\in I}X_i$ **onto** $\Pi_{j\in J}(X|J)_j$ (page 36). This is before the axiom of choice is introduced.

However, I think that without AC, we **can't** conclusively say that $f$ is indeed a surjection (even if $\forall i(X_i\neq\emptyset)$). Am I correct?

---

For a function $g:Y\to Z$ and for $X\subset Y$, $f|X$ denotes the restriction of $f$ to $X$.

Comment: We can't say it's surjective yet, no. But I don't think "onto" here needs to be interpreted as meaning surjective either.

Comment: @ZhenLin I guess I'll go with what you say.

Comment: The standard usage of "onto" is that the map is surjective. If Halmos is not assuming choice in this part of the book, this looks like a slip on his part. Yes, as you say, without assuming the axiom of choice, surjectivity cannot be proved. Really, all you need is that the product is nonempty to conclude surjectivity of the projections but, of course, that all such products are nonempty is precisely the axiom of choice.